Querying for roads, highways, etc. (not including pedestrian paths, park trails, parking lots) on OSM overpass
I am trying to query for just motor roads, highways, streets, residential roads, etc. while filtering out things such as parking lots, pedestrian paths, and park trails on OSM overpass turbo.
Currently, this is the query I'm using but I notice that it omits some major highways and residential roads.
[out:json];
nwr({{bbox}});
(way(area)["highway"~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|secondary_link|tertiary_link|residential|unclassified|living_street|)$"];>;);
out;


Show some examples about features which get filtered out. Use OSM links to the features, like https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/141446053#map=16/51.6469/-0.3341&layers=D

area is not the result of nwr({{bbox}}). According to your way of query you can use:
[out:json];
nwr({{bbox}});
(way ._ ["highway"~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|secondary_link|tertiary_link|residential|unclassified|living_street|)$"];>;);
out;

With ._ as result of nwr({{bbox}}). 
One of other options would be to write directly:
[out:json];
(way({{bbox}})["highway"~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|secondary_link|tertiary_link|residential|unclassified|living_street|)$"];>;);
out;

